# Lists load in edit mode

Tags: list-view, quick-edit

So I'm not sure how exactly this problem is caused, but about every other time I visit my SharePoint team site, the list is in edit mode. The screen is moved about halfway down to center on the list, and it says "stop editing" like it loaded in edit mode. Thoughts?

Comment: Your list are using a view based on quick edit. Change the view by editing the site and editing the list view webpart.

Comment: Can you paste the URL ? Perhaps sometinh in the URL is causing the edit mode...

Comment: https://projectadvocatesllc.sharepoint.com/sites/sabienssandbox/SitePages/Home.aspx#InplviewHasha64be494-5d2c-49e8-8f7d-4a832d66e019=ShowInGrid%3DTrue